# Kotlin junit MockK runner

Tags: kotlin, junit, mockk

I'm trying to write unit tests using `Kotlin` and [MockK](https://github.com/mockk/mockk) framework. If tests are written using `junit 5` framework it's possible to run them using `MockKExtension`.

```
@ExtendWith(MockKExtension::class)
```

But for `junit 4` tests is there a `MockK` runner?
Like:

```
@RunWith(....)
```

Without such runner it's required to initialize mocks manually.

```
private val a: A = mockK()
```

Is it possible to initialize kotlin mocks using annotation with `junit 4`?

```
@MockK
private lateinit var a: A
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick answer is no.

BUT. It's very simple to use MockK with JUnit 4:

All you need is code like this:

```
class CarTest {
  @MockK
  lateinit var car1: Car
  @Before
  fun setUp() = MockKAnnotations.init(this, relaxUnitFun = true) // turn relaxUnitFun on for all mocks
  // And so on…
```

BTW, it's not hand-crafted example, it's from [official documentation](https://mockk.io/#annotations)

Answer (score 0):

The better way would be to use the official MockKRule(this)

```
@get:Rule
  val mockkRule = MockKRule(this)

  @MockK
  lateinit var car1: Car

  @RelaxedMockK
  lateinit var car2: Car
```